# Applying a function to a combination of elements in a row conditional on combinations of values in different rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

Let's say I have the following command:

```
comb = ((x, y, (256 - (x - y))/100) for x, y in combinations(df['hh'], 2) if x != y)
series = Series(list(g) for k, g in groupby(comb, key=itemgetter(0)))
```

I have another row called df['name'] and what I want to get is something like:

```
series = ((x, y, (256 - (x - y))/100) for x, y in combinations(df['hh'], 2) if df['name'].x.split('_')[0] != df['name'].y.split('_')[0])
```

how I could do that ?

**Edit:**
My data frame is something like

```
name  hh
A_10  12
A_11  10
B_10  7 
B_11  6
B_12  5
C_09  14
```

Comment: can you include what would be the expected result on that input ?